# Creating a combination table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails. I am having no problem creating normal tables, but I am trying to figure out how to create a combination table. So, for example there would be a sport table and a team table. I would then like to create one table that is an over all sport-team table that has a sport and a team that's values come from the corresponding table. Would I just make the sport and team tables belong to the overall table or is there a different way. How would I go about doing it.

Comment: In rails these are called join tables, ill post a link to the docs and an answer explaining them shortly

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to rails so thank you for taking the time to answer @TMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails guide for associations is a great help at these things: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

This is specifically a has and belongs to many relationship because you want sports to have and belong to many teams.

The migration should look like this:

```
class CreateSportsTeamsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sports_teams, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :sport_id
      t.integer :team_id
    end
    add_index :sports_teams, [:sport_id, :team_id]
  end
end
```

And the models should look like this:

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
end
```

And then to use them:

```
lax = Sport.create(name: "Lacrosse")
lax.teams << Team.create(name: "Johns Hopkins University")
lax.teams.first.name                     #=> Johns Hopkins University
jhu = Team.first
jhu.sports.create(name: "Ultimate Frisbee")  # Note there are many different ways to create the association
puts "#{jhu.name} is the best at #{jhu.sports.collect{ |sport| sport.name }.join(' and ')}"
```

And then you should know some real awesome facts